# Building Multiple Charts Using Chart JS in an Angular Application

Tags: angular, chart.js

I created a component to every type of charts (pie, bars, lines...)
For example:
**bar-chart.component.html**

```
<canvas id="{{idChart}}"></canvas>
```

**bar-chart.component.ts**

```
 @Input() idChart:any;

ngOnInit(): void {
    new Chart(this.idChart, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple'],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Label Teste',
            data: [19, 12, 10, 8, 7],
            backgroundColor: [
              '#4B79A1',
              '#6693BD',
              '#82AED9',
              '#9ECAF6',
              '#BBE6FF',
            ],
            borderColor: [
              '#4B79A1',
              '#6693BD',
              '#82AED9',
              '#9ECAF6',
              '#BBE6FF',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1,
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
        },
      },
    });   }
```

I have a component called home and it should contain several charts:

```
<div class="barCharts">
  <app-bar-chart idChart='myBarChart1'></app-bar-chart>
  <app-bar-chart idChart='myBarChart2'></app-bar-chart>
  <app-bar-chart idChart='myBarChart3'></app-bar-chart>
</div>
```

however I have two types of errors:

> Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item
> Because of the ID send my input property

and

> Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before
> the canvas can be reused.

because there is more than on chart(I have different Ids)

I tried to put it inside a variable and then destroy the chart instance using:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.myChart ? this.myChart.destroy() : null
...
}
```

But I was not successful

Comment: Please ask your question in English. Or go to https://es.stackoverflow.com to ask in Spanish.

Comment: Stack Overlow is an English-language site, please see https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see was in english stack overflow. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your chart creation code inside `ngAfterViewInit()` instead of `ngOnInt()`.

The `ngAfterViewInit()` is invoked once the component view is initialized. At this point you can be sure, the `canvas` exists.

> For further details, please consult [lifecycle event sequence](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence) from the `Angular` documentation.